# Cardboard Application is not drawing anything?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cardboard

I am building a cardboard application so I downloaded one the cardboard-java-sample.
In my own project I build an activity which has the same contents as the TreasureHuntActivity. But when I run it the surfce is being created. but the ondraw functions are never called. Any idea or suggestion will be much apprichiated:)

Comment: If you rotate the device around 180 degrees (front to back), is it still black?

Comment: Yes! I just debuged it again and figured out that the first frame is actually drawn correctly but then every frame is black again...

Comment: OK. It still sounds the like the issue I was facing. I noticed that it was black but if I rotated the device around the scene would show (not TreasureHunt though). I figured out I had to rotate the pose I was getting by 180 degrees. Have you tried forcing landscape mode?

Comment: Yes it is in landscape mode if that is what you mean. + I am still rendering the floor so whereever I turn there should be the floor visible

Comment: @reden do you have any idea?

Comment: Not currently, sorry. It sounds similar to my issue but I'm not sure what was causing it. I'd check what the pose the application receives looks like. Also, maybe adding what device you're testing on might be helpful for others. And if other cardboard apps work as expected.

Comment: Anything interesting showing up in adb logcat? (It's a bit hard to help without code or logs)